# Trying to plot Spanning tree in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, network-analysis, spanning-tree

I am trying to plot, like the title already says, a spanning tree.

But I am getting following error if I try to plot my graph:

> ```
> Error using rng
> Too many input arguments.
>
> Error in matlab.internal.graph.MLGraph/forceLayout>layoutOneConnComp (line 82)
>     oldstate = rng(0,'twister');
>
> Error in matlab.internal.graph.MLGraph/forceLayout (line 55)
>         [x,y] = layoutOneConnComp(x,y,sources,targets,iterations);
>
> Error in matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot/layoutforce
>
> Error in matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot/layout>layoutauto
>
> Error in matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot/layout
>
> Error in matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot
>
> Error in graph/plot (line 110)
> hObj = matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.GraphPlot('BasicGraph', ...
> ```

Additional Information:

```
GrangerLandN={ 'X' 'Y' 'Z' ...}';
GrangerCoal={ 'A' 'B' 'C' ...}'; 
GrangerValues=(1,2,3,...)'; 

GG=graph(GrangerLandN,GrangerCoal,GrangerValues)

GG = 

  graph with properties:

    Edges: [100×2 table]
    Nodes: [20×1 table]

plot(GG) %also tried plot(GG,'EgdesLabel',GG.Edges.Weight) but both are throwing the error stated above.
```

Tried the same with less observations and it worked perfectly fine. What is the reason for the error, and how can I fix the code?

Comment: "Error using rng Too many input arguments." This sounds like you've overwritten (shadowed) the default `rng` function. If `which rng` does not return `<something>/toolbox/matlab/randfun/rng.m` then you need to delete (or rename) the file indicated there.

Answer (score 1):

The key functions used for this example are `pplot` and `minspan` from the [MATLOG toolbox](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/). The code below creates a network and then plots a **minimum spanning tree** ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree)).

Some supporting functions from MATLOG are also used (see code below) to create the example (taken from [MATLOG](https://people.engr.ncsu.edu/kay/matlog/MatlogRef.htm) documentation).

```
%% 2. Create Delaunay Network from Cities Centered around Atlanta
%% Make network using cities of 30k pop. within 150 miles of Atlanta
Atl = uscity('XY',mand({'Atlanta'},uscity('Name'),{'GA'},uscity('ST')));
[Name,XY]=uscity10k('Name','XY', ...
   (dists(Atl,uscity10k('XY'),'mi') < 150)' & uscity10k('Pop') > 30000);
makemap(XY)
pplot(XY,'r.')

%% Use Delaunay triangulation as road network
tri = delaunay(XY(:,1),XY(:,2));  % Delaunay triangulation
IJ = tri2list(tri);  % Convert to arc list
d = diag(dists(XY(IJ(:,1),:),XY(abs(IJ(:,2)),:),'mi'));
d = d * 1.2;  % Convert great circle to estimated road distances
d = round(d);
IJD = [IJ d];
pplot(IJD,XY,'m-')
pplot(IJD,num2cellstr(d),XY)

%% Minimum Spanning Tree (Kruskal algorithm)
t = minspan(IJD);
pplot(IJD(t~=0,:),XY,'b-','LineWidth',2,'DisplayName','minspan')
```

[image: Minimum Spanning Tree]

Comment: @CrisLuengo, two reasons.  (1) OP asked this 10 months ago...my answer is for future seekers more than for OP.  (2) this is they way I knew how to do it and I believe aspects of `pplot` or components may help OP.  Would you prefer me to delete my answer?

Comment: No, not at all. I would have downvoted it if I thought it was useless. It is actually quite a good answer, it just does't directly answer this question. :)

Comment: I honestly just didn't know how to directly answer it using the OP's approach but I knew how to do it with this.  I appreciate the feedback.